# Is there a nicer way to prepend if not nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a bunch of environment variables with my config in them:

```
DB_HOSTNAME=something.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORTNUM=9999
DB_USERNAME=production
DB_PASSWORD=xyzzy
```

To make a DB connect string from them it's something like:

```
"postgres://" +
"#{ENV['DB_USERNAME']}#{ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] ? ":#{ENV['DB_PASSWORD']}" : nil}" + 
"@#{ENV['DB_HOSTNAME']}#{ENV['DB_PORTNUM'] ? ":#{ENV['DB_PORTNUM']}" : nil}" +
"/proper_scraper_#{$environment}"
```

That way it works in development/test where `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_PORTNUM` aren't set, and works in production where they are. But this bit is ugly:

```
ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] ? ":#{ENV['DB_PASSWORD']}" : nil
```

The desired semantics are: prepend if not nil and return nil otherwise. Ideally it would be something like this:

```
ENV['DB_PASSWORD'].try(:prepend, ':')
```

Using Object.try something like this:

```
  def try method, *args
    send(method, *args) if respond_to? method
  end
```

But that doesn't work because prepend mutates the string (why?) and env strings are frozen. The alternative:

```
ENV['DB_PASSWORD'].dup.try(:prepend, ':')
```

But this doesn't work when the environment variable is not set because you can't dup nil.

Is there a nice one-liner here or am I stuck with the messiness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use objects and the standard library:

```
require 'uri'

u = URI::Generic.build(
    scheme: "postgres", 
    host: ENV["DB_HOSTNAME"], 
    port: ENV["DB_PORTNUM"], 
    path: "/proper_scraper_#{$environment}",
)

u.user = ENV["DB_USERNAME"]
u.password = ENV["DB_PASSWORD"]

puts u.to_s
```

Comment: That's true and may well be the best solution. But it feels like overkill to pull in a whole new `require` just for some simple string concatenation.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken "Object#try" comes from Rails, it's arguably the more heavy-handed, require-ful solution.

Comment: Actually I monkey-patched it in myself using the implementation I showed in the question. But you're right, and I think your solution is probably the most intention-revealing that I've seen so far.

Comment: Using URI is a nice path, but I'd be concerned with URI inadvertently encoding characters that the DBM expects to be unencoded. Using URI::Generic *should* avoid that, but it'd be good to check for those sort of cases.

Answer (score 4):

It's unfortunate that both `String#insert` and `String#prepend` modify the strings, but [`String#sub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-sub) should work:

```
ENV['DB_PASSWORD'].try(:sub,'',':')
```

Or with a bit more intention:

```
ENV['DB_PASSWORD'].try(:sub,/^/,':')
```

Comment: Right! It would be ideal if `prepend` was `prepend!` and there was also the symmetric `prepend`. `sub` is a solid answer, I hadn't thought of that and it has the right semantics, but it's not as intention-revealing as I'd like - takes a bit of reading.

Answer (score 1):

If `Object#try` happens to support blocks (like ActiveSupport’s),

```
ENV['DB_PASSWORD'].try { |s| ":#{s}" }
```

Comment: I've monkey-patched it in as I showed in the question, so my implementation doesn't currently support blocks. But the look of this is probably my preference. Maybe I'll steal the ActiveSupport implementation.

Answer (score 1):

From ruby `2.3` you can use the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/NEWS-2_3_0.html#label-Language+changes) in combination with [`String#sub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-sub) (As [`@Matt`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2700898/matt) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27751433/839429))

```
ENV["DB_PASSWORD]&.sub(/^/, ":")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Your readability has really suffered because you're trying to do it all in a single line. Don't do that.

I'd do something like:

Set up the ENV for the example...

```
ENV['DB_HOSTNAME'] = 'something.rds.amazonaws.com'
ENV['DB_PORTNUM'] = '9999'
ENV['DB_USERNAME'] = 'production'
ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] = 'xyzzy'
```

The real code starts here:

```
$environment = 'production'
db_hostname, db_portnum, db_username, db_password = %w[
  DB_HOSTNAME
  DB_PORTNUM
  DB_USERNAME
  DB_PASSWORD
].map{ |e| ENV[e] }

db_password = ':' + db_password if db_password
db_portnum = ':' + db_portnum if db_portnum

DSN = "postgres://%s%s@%s%s%s" % [
  db_username,
  db_password,
  db_hostname,
  db_portnum,
  "/proper_scraper_#{$environment}"
]
DSN # => "postgres://production:xyzzy@something.rds.amazonaws.com:9999/proper_scraper_production"
```

Ternary statements are replacements for `if`/`then`/`else` statements, not for simple `if`/`then`. Trying to make them fit only results in confusing code, so don't go there.

People get enamored with cramming code all in one line, and, a long time ago, back when we used interpreted BASIC, it helped speed up the code, but today's languages rarely benefit from that. Instead, what happens is it makes code indecipherable. Writing code that is indecipherable is a fast path to being called up to explain yourself in a code-review, followed by being told to rewrite it and never do it again.

Comment: I agree in general but disagree in this case. The semantics here aren't complicated so the code shouldn't be. Your implementation will take me two minutes to understand because there's so much happening there. That's probably because I'm dense but we all are at times. It should be possible to reveal the intention of this code much more quickly than two minutes. It's just not complicated. Amit's answer is the best for that, I think - though I still think Ruby should provide a nicer way to do it as string concat.